# Why doesn't my Javascript file run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reddit

```
  "name": "javascript-development-environment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "CS 235 package.json file for programming projects",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node buildScripts/startMessage.js",
    "redditImgGet": "babel-node buildScripts/srcReddit.js",
    "install": "npm install",
    "start":"npm-run-all --parallel security-check open:src",
    "security-check": "nsp check",
    "open:src": "babel-node buildScripts/srcServer.js"
  },
```

This is currently my `package.json`. I am trying to call the script which obtains an image from *reddit*. The inside of `srcReddit.js` is shown below:

```
var snoowrap = require('snoowrap');

console.log("Starting Reddit Image Fetcher");

const otherRequester = new snoowrap({
    userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
    clientId: 'Cf8kGqDSuT17xw',
    clientSecret: 'DDmMslUwMJW1ZM5JTc07zJDpC8k',
    username: 'sharan100',
    password: 'Magewindu100'
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

r.getHot().map(post => post.title).then(console.log);

console.log("Ending Reddit Image Fetcher");
```

For this, I am using the wrapper [snoowrap](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap) for the [reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/). Now when I do a `npm start`, I for some reason get this below:

[image]

No idea why the `console.log` messages do not appear. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm start` runs the `start` task and it does not refer to the `redditImgGet` task at any time, it seems.

I assume you should change your `start` task to

```
npm-run-all --parallel security-check open:src redditImgGet
```

Or just run the task directly

```
npm run redditImgGet
```

Otherwise, I don't see where you could expect the `srcReddit` file to log anything.

Comment: That's weird, because the `prestart` also happens either ways. So I assumed that I didn't need to modify the `start` script. How silly of me!